# what can or cannot be done with a controller created in a module Vs controller created globally?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Have seen various angular JS examples and I get the hint that I should define controllers on a module rather than a global definition.

Say I have an app that has `<body ng-app='mymodule'>` - inside body it can acknowledge controllers created in mymodule and controllers created globally.

1. The controller defined on the module will not have access to any **global
   variables** as compared to the global controller. True/False ?
2. Any other important points to note here  ?

Answer (score 2):

> The controller defined on the module will not have access to any global variables as compared to the global controller. True ?

False. Global variables are, well, global. You can access them from within the controller, but you shouldn't, unless testing isn't a concern for you - and it definitely should be.

> Any other important points to note here ?

A global controller cannot use services from other modules but from Angular itself. If you want to use components defined in another modules (directives, factories, providers, etc.) you'll have to create your own module and declare them as dependencies so you can inject the bits you need wherever you need them.

The only use for a global controller, IMO, is to demonstrate Angular in a simple, easy-to-understand way. Don't use it in production.

**Update**

As @dotnetcoder pointed out in the comments, apparently due to the way Angular loads modules, a global controller can actually access the services from a module if that module was already loaded by the framework. I stand corrected. But, although technically possible, I can't think of any reason anyone should do that and I stand by what I've said previously: don't use global controllers in production.

Comment: actually ( and to my surprise) it seems a global controller can access the services from a module . I put this jsfiddle example that is accessing a factory in a global controller http://jsfiddle.net/JrXeb/

Comment: I had to dig in the Angular source code in order to understand what's going on here. If I got it right, Angular first loads the module defined in the `ng-app` attribute together with all of its dependencies. Then it processes the `ng-controller` directive and tries to resolve the controller dependencies by looking at all services previously loaded. If it finds everything needed to execute the controller, it does it. That's unexpected, at least for me. I guess I should stop reading the docs and start learning from the Angular source code. :)